# Is it possible to just change the crankshaft and bearing and 1 connecting rod with out changing the heads on the vehicle

Tags: crankshaft

I need to replace the Crankshaft and bearings in my 2001 toyota 4 runner is it possible to change with out replacing the heads.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you saying this as if you don't want to take the heads off? If so and you want to replace a connecting rod, it cannot be done. To change the rod, the piston has to come out, which goes out the top of the block, which means the head has to come off.

Answer (score 4):

It is most probably possible to change crank and bearings, but to change the con-rod the piston has to come out so the head has to come off.

Comment: Ok what happen to my 4 runner is 1 of the connecting rods was loose so it messed up the crank shaft and the bearing so my macanic says we caught on time that it did not ruin the heads on it do you think that just changing the connecting rod and all the bearing and the crankshaft that it will run right.

Comment: If there was too much play due to that con-rod and bearing then the piston will have hit the valves which means the head will have to come off to sort them....

Comment: One more question ok if there were metal in the oil will the motor have to be cleaned out really good another macinic said that if it was not cleaned out really good the same thing would happen again.

Comment: Definitely yes and its probably more cost and time effective to take the engine out and have easy access. But that is what I would do...

Comment: How rough was it driven?

Comment: It wasent driven to rough it was parked as soon as we heard the noise so it didnt damage the heads on it   and we took the motor out already were about to put in a new crankshaft and 1 connecting rod and all the bearings

Comment: Oh yea my son actully bought this 2001 4 runner on craigs list and only drove it for 15 days when this happen he payed 3000 for it pretty said how people can do something like this ha!!